# Delicious API feeds.delicious.com no more?

Tags: api, rest, delicious-api

In the past, I've been using the [Delicious API](https://delicious.com/rss) available under `feeds.delicious.com`. When running this code today, I found out that the corresponding hostname is not available any longer (checked first time some days ago). I've already asked Delicious support directly about the state of the API, but not yet received an answer. So I thought anybody here might have more recent information, whether this is some temporary outage or the API has been cut completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was likely part of the rollback to Delicious's old architecture in January 2016](http://blog.delicious.com/2016/01/delicious-changes/):

> Fortunately for us, the version that the javascript site replaced has been kept alive at previous.delicious.com. This was built using a much more traditional framework, and it’s great! In fact, many of our longtime users have continued to prefer it over the main site, and frankly, so do we. Therefore, we are switching to this platform for our main site, and this transition will position us to quickly iterate in our ongoing efforts to keep Delicious thriving.

The auth URL on [the documentation's OAuth page](https://github.com/domainersuitedev/delicious-api/blob/master/api/oauth.md) (`delicious.com/auth/authorize`) 404's for me as well, so I have a feeling this has indeed been retired.